# Stoke's Theorem verification with $S$ as a Square.

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

The Vector field $F$ is given by $\mathbf{F}=\left\langle e^{y-z}, 0,0\right\rangle$. Consider the square $S$ with vertices $(9,0,4),(9,9,4),(0,9,4) \text {, and }(0,0,4) \text {. }$

I need to verify Stokes' theorem. I have done the line integral part which i got it as:
$$\oint_{C} \vec{F} \cdot \overrightarrow{d l}=81\left(e^{-5}+e^{4}\right)$$

Now we have $$\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{F}=-e^{y-z}(\hat{j}+\hat{k})$$

Also the unit outward normal to the square $S$ which is in $z=4$ plane is $\hat{n}=\hat{k}$. So we have:
$$\iint_{S}(\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}) \cdot \hat{n} d s=\iint_{S}-e^{y-z} d s=-e^{-4}\iint_{S}e^ydydx=-e^{-4} \int_{x=0}^{9} \int_{y=0}^{9} e^{y} d y d x=9\left(e^{5}-e^{-4}\right)$$

Where i went wrong?

Comment: The curl of the vector field is $e^{y-z}(\hat j + \hat k)$ but your final answer dropped that minus sign so you ended up with the right answer.

Comment: Given you are taking the unit normal vector as $\hat k$, the answer should be $9\left(e^{-4} - e^{5}\right)$. Also going in anticlockwise direction, the line integral would come to the same.

Comment: Also for a planar surface, _outward_ normal may not mean much. You may want to write _upward_ normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line integral is wrong. It should be:

$\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{l}=\int_0^9 e^{9-4} dx + \int_9^0 e^{0-4} dx=9(e^5-e^{-4})$

(You only have to consider the line integrals from (0,9,4) to (9,9,4) and (9,0,4) to (0,0,4) since the field is perpendicular to the path of integration on the other two sides of the square.)